# Why do I have a trailing column when reading a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, multiple-columns, ruby-parser

I have a CSV file whith the following structure:

```
"customer_id";"customer_name";"quantity";
"id1234";"Henry";"15";
```

Parsing with Ruby's standard CSV lib:

```
csv_data = CSV.read(pathtofile,{
    :headers => :first_row,
    :col_sep => ";",
    :quote_char => '"'
    :row_sep => "\r\n" #setting it to "\r" or "\n" results in MalformedCSVError
})

puts csv_data.headers.count #4
```

I don't understand why the parsing seems to result in four columns although the file only contains three. Is this not the right approach to parse the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `;` at the end of each row is implying another field, even though there is no value.

I would either remove the trailing `;`'s or just ignore the fourth field when it is parsed.

Comment: I'll remove the trailing ; to have clean data to work with. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing `;` is the culprit.

You can preprocess the file, stripping the trailing `;`, but that incurs unnecessary overhead.

You can post-process the returned array of data from CSV using something like this:

```
csv_data = CSV.read(...).map(&:pop)
```

That will iterate over the sub-arrays, removing the last element in each. The problem is that `read` isn't scalable, so you might want to rethink using it and instead, use `CSV.foreach` to read the file line by line and then pop the last value as they're returned to you.